# NSKeyedUnarchiver consumes lots of memory, never freed

Tags: ios, swift, memory, nskeyedunarchiver

I'm working on an app having to deal with large plist files. I can see that memory usage increases each times the files are read.

I have three plist files a, b and c with a total size of 21 MB.

The memory usage is:
21 MB app started, no files read,
69 MB after first import of the three files,
91 MB after second import,
95 MB 3rd import,
103 MB 4th,
105 MB 5th,
106 MB 6th.

The code doing the work:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let files = [ "a", "b", "c" ]

    for fileName in files {
        let _ = load(fileName)
    }
}

func load(_ name: String) -> Any? {
    let documents = Bundle.main.bundlePath as NSString
    let filePath = documents.appendingPathComponent("\(name).plist")
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath)
}
```

Why is the mem increasing?

[image: Memory usage increases after each import]

After spending lots of hours in Instruments I finally pinned down the problem to the line

`NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath)`

If I change that line to:

```
let _ = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath)
return ""
```

The problem is still there. What is going on in `unarchiveObject`?

I have also tested (suggested in comment) assigning the result to `var x` and then `x = nil` but no improvement.

Is there any fix for this or a workaround?

Thank you for reading.

Ps. I have created a test project illustrating the issue in this repo

https://github.com/jkufver/unarchiver-mem-issue.git

Comment: I've tested your project. The memory is released fine. Not right away though. After about 20 clicks on "Load" button the memory didn't exceed ~100Mb. Looks like ARC manages the memory correctly.

Comment: I expected the mem to go back to 21 MB or so. What should I expect? Does not ARC free right the way?

Comment: you should expect the memory not growing constantly. ARC does its job when it's most convenient for it. You can try to declare a class property to store the result of the `unarchiveObject` and then make it `nil` - this will reduce the memory but not too much.